# Changing the WebLogic Domain location

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g

I am currently setting up a new dev environment, and have come to the final stage where I am trying to run a build.

However, one of the ANT targets is trying to create a directory, which is currently set to "C:\workspace\domains\Online" however for security reasons (they say anyway...) we do not have full access to the C: drive, so I have my domain setup in an alternate location. Where is this Domain Home/Root variable kept?

Answer (score 1):

Well in my own domain there is in file `<domain>/bin/setDomainEnv.bat` the following line:

```
set DOMAIN_HOME=D:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\domain_name
```

However since you are using some Ant build file to create your domain, maybe something is hardcoded in them or is one of the properties passed to this file.

Comment: That's exactly what it was. A build file that had been supplied by somebody else had been hardcoded! Not sure why they couldn't follow the convention!

Comment: great! please close the question.

Answer (score 0):

An ANT build file that had been supplied by somebody else had been hardcoded! Not sure why they couldn't follow the convention! It just so happened that the location that had been hardcoded was the same as my old workspace, thus the confusion.

Thanks all.